# How to get coordinate value of any point on a curve?

Tags: processing

I wrote a piece of code to generate a `curve` across all the given points, the code is as followed. It is coded in `processing PDE` and based on `curveVertex()` function.
Is there any way to get `coordinate` `value(x, y)` of any point on this `curve`?

```java
int[] lineData = new int[10];

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  intiate();
}

void intiate() {
  for (int i = 0; i < lineData.length; i ++) {
  lineData[i] = int(random(100, 600));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);  
  translate(100,0);
  beginShape();
  noFill();
  curveVertex(0, lineData[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < lineData.length; i ++) {
  strokeWeight(1);
  curveVertex(i*60, lineData[i]);
 }
 curveVertex((lineData.length-1)*60, lineData[lineData.length-1]);
 endShape();

 for (int i = 0; i < lineData.length; i ++) {
   strokeWeight(5);
   point(i*60, lineData[i]);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'r') {
    intiate();
  }
}
```

================================

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the position of the points being drawn, you should use the [`curvePoint()`](https://processing.org/reference/curvePoint_.html) function instead.

The `curvePoint()` function doesn't draw the points, it returns their positions. From the reference:

> ## curvePoint()
>
> Evaluates the curve at point t for points a, b, c, d. The parameter t
>   may range from 0 (the start of the curve) and 1 (the end of the
>   curve). a and d are points on the curve, and b and c are the control
>   points. This can be used once with the x coordinates and a second time
>   with the y coordinates to get the location of a curve at t.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ```java
> a float: coordinate of first point on the curve
> b float: coordinate of second point on the curve
> c float: coordinate of third point on the curve
> d float: coordinate of fourth point on the curve
> t float: value between 0 and 1
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> ```java
> noFill();
> curve(5, 26, 5, 26, 73, 24, 73, 61);
> curve(5, 26, 73, 24, 73, 61, 15, 65);
> fill(255);
> ellipseMode(CENTER);
> int steps = 6;
> for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
>   float t = i / float(steps);
>   float x = curvePoint(5, 5, 73, 73, t);
>   float y = curvePoint(26, 26, 24, 61, t);
>   ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
>   x = curvePoint(5, 73, 73, 15, t);
>   y = curvePoint(26, 24, 61, 65, t);
>   ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[curvePoint() can be used to pick coordinate value of point on a given curve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNWMM.png)